# What is the geometric interpretation of the first Hochschild homology group of path algebra constructed from a directed graph?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, directed-graphs, hochschild-homology

Let $\mathcal{G} = (V, E, s, t)$ is a directed graph, where $V$ - the set of its vertices, $E$ - the set of its edges, $s: E \rightarrow V, s((v_1, v_2)) = v_1$ and $t: E \rightarrow V, s((v_1, v_2)) = v_2$.

Let $A=\mathbb{C}\mathcal{G}$ be a path algebra associated to the digraph $\mathcal{G}$. Then, the first Hochschild homology group of $A$ is $HH_1(A) = \{ a_0 \otimes a_1 \in A^{\otimes 2} | a_0 a_1 = a_1 a_0\} / \{ a_0 a_1 \otimes a_2 - a_0 \otimes a_1 a_2 + a_2 a_0 \otimes a_1 | a_0, a_1, a_2 \in A\}$.

There is, for example, a geometric interpretation of the $n$-th simplicial homology: it is a space of the $n$-dimensional holes. Can the first Hochschild homology group of path algebra be interpreted geometrically in terms of the underlying digraph in the same sense?

UPD

1. First of all, I am interested in the case of an acyclic digraph. In this case, there is a formula for dimensionality of the first Hochschild homology group of path algebra presented, for example, in this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.00462): $dim HH_1(A) = 1 - |V(\mathcal{G})| + \sum_{e \in E(\mathcal{G})} dim e_{t(e)} A e_{s(e)}$, where $e_{t(e)} A e_{s(e)}$ is a subspace generated by all the paths from $e_{s(e)}$ to $e_{t(e)}$. It means that the first Hochschild homology group of path algebra of a finite cyclic digraph is not zero. But this result does not give a geometric intuition.
2. I have found a paper ([https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Allegretti.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Allegretti.pdf)) which the first Hochschild homology group is viewed as the module of 1-differential forms of non-commutative space in. Also, there is a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0405v1) showing the relationship between the Hochschild homology and the cohomology of the free loop space. In both cases, the geometric interpretation of the results in terms of the underlying digraph is not clear for me. But I hope, it may be useful for giving an answer to the question.

Thank you!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160098/hochschild-homology-of-quiver-algebras

Comment: @AaronBergman , thank you for the link! But I can only find the computation of the dimensionality of Hochschild homology of path algebra, but not the geometric interpretation in terms of digraph.

Comment: Look up the canonical projective resolution for a quiver, say in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869398975998

Comment: @AaronBergman, excuse me, could you, please, point, which resolution do you mean in this article? It is not clear for me, which resolution is the canonical projective one. There is a post [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299169/intuition-behind-the-canonical-projective-resolution-of-a-quiver-representation) with the canonical projective resolution mentioned. But there is a proof in the paragraph 1.4 of [link](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/notes_quivers_rev.pdf) that this resolution is an exact sequence. So, I am not sure that it could be used for computation of homology.

Comment: I'm  not sure what you're asking. Hochschild homology is a Tor, and you compute it using a projective resolution in the usual fashion.

Comment: @AaronBergman, sorry for elementary questions: I've just started learning homalg. I tried to compute $HH$ and got them 0 (they are actually not). I'll be very glad if you point out where I made a mistake! Here are what I've computed: $HH_0(A)=ker(A\otimes_{A^e}A\rightarrow0)/im(id\otimes_{A^e}u)=(A\otimes_{A^e}A)/(A\otimes_{A^e}\bigoplus_{i\in Q_0}Ae_iA)=0$, $HH_1(A)=ker(id\otimes_{A^e}u)/im(id\otimes_{A^e}v)=\{a\otimes_{A^e}\bigoplus_{i\in Q_0}b_i\otimes_Kc_i|a\otimes_{A^e}\bigoplus_{i\in Q_0}b_ic_i=0\}/im(id\otimes_{A^e}v)=0/\ldots=0 (u(a\otimes b)=ab,v(a\otimes b)=a\otimes pb-ap\otimes b)$

Comment: I’m sorry. I can’t figure out what you’re doing here. I don’t think a mathoverflow comment thread is an appropriate place for this sort of thing, and I encourage you to find someone in your department who can help you.